# Galton-Watson process: branching property

Tags: pr.probability, trees

I am looking for the definition of the ‚branching property‘ of a Galton Watson process. Can someone give me an example about it?

It looks to me like an independence.

I have a branching processes book, but there is the branching property only for lines defined. I need it special for a Galton-Watson Process.

BR, Fynn

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process

Comment: I don’t see on Wikipedia the definition of the branching property.

Comment: There are $X_n$ individuals (bacteria) in the  $n$-th generation. Each individual $j$ in the $n$-th generation  yields $\xi_j^{(n))$ *branches*, or successors.   Hence the word *branching process*. Draw a picture.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu fine - but that still doesn't tell you what people customarily mean when they use the phrase "branching property"!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the "branching property" is an independence property for the Galton-Watson tree (or "Bienaymé tree"). People typically use the phrase to refer to some version of the following fact. Condition on the event that the root vertex has $k$ children. Call those children $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$. Then the $k$ subtrees rooted at $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$ are independent, and each one has the distribution of the original tree.

Comment: Do you maybe know where i can find the formalised definition of your comment?